# Como Modificar registros linea por linea de un TXT con C#?

Tags: c#, bucles, foreach, txt, str-replace

Tengo un problema con mi codigo, estoy realizando un programa que se encarga de leer un archivo TXT línea por línea y que cuando se encuentre la palabra "PENDIENTE", lo reemplace por la palabra "ENVIADO", he podido realizarlo con una línea pero al haber mas líneas solo me trae una y es la del ultimo registro como se mostrara mas adelante,

Mi txt contiene las siguientes dos lineas que estan separadas por un delimitador "|" :

**Alerta_MantenimMecanicoG1**|**Aviso N° 10003 el CS_VIQMEL -AUSVN /n /n Area: PLTXT /n /n Equipo: CS_VIQMEL- EQUNR +” - ”+ EQKTX /n /n Trabajo: QMARTX /n /n Servicio: CS_VIQMEL -INGRP+” - ”+ INNAM /n /n Solicitante: SNAME /n /n Prioridad: PRIOKX /n /n Descripción Aviso: CS_VIQMEL- QMTXT**|**03/11/2022**|**16:51:32**|**PENDIENTE**

**Alerta_MantenimMecanicoG1|Aviso N° 20003 el CS_VIQMEL -AUSVN /n /n Area: PLTXT /n /n Equipo: CS_VIQMEL- EQUNR +” - ”+ EQKTX /n /n Trabajo: QMARTX /n /n Servicio: CS_VIQMEL -INGRP+” - ”+ INNAM /n /n Solicitante: SNAME /n /n Prioridad: PRIOKX /n /n Descripción Aviso: CS_VIQMEL- QMTXT**|**03/11/2022**|**16:51:37**|**PENDIENTE**

Mi codigo :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace LectorEnvioMsgWsap
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            
            try
            {
                string[] filas = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\temp\MensajesxEnviarWsap2.txt");
                string estado = "PENDIENTE";
                foreach (string fila in filas)  
                {
                    if (fila.Contains(estado))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(fila);
                        string cadena = fila.Replace(estado, "ENVIADO");
                        TextWriter SobreEscribirArchivo = new StreamWriter(@"C:\temp\MensajesxEnviarWsap2.txt", false);
                        SobreEscribirArchivo.Write(cadena);
                        SobreEscribirArchivo.Close();
                    }
                    
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Si se produce un error al eliminar lo mostramos
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

            System.Console.ReadLine();
        }
       
    }
}
```

cuando ejectuto el programa el resultado del archivo txt es el siguiente:

**Alerta_MantenimMecanicoG1**|**Aviso N° 20003 el CS_VIQMEL -AUSVN /n /n Area: PLTXT /n /n Equipo: CS_VIQMEL- EQUNR +” - ”+ EQKTX /n /n Trabajo: QMARTX /n /n Servicio: CS_VIQMEL -INGRP+” - ”+ INNAM /n /n Solicitante: SNAME /n /n Prioridad: PRIOKX /n /n Descripción Aviso: CS_VIQMEL- QMTXT**|**03/11/2022**|**16:51:37**|**ENVIADO**

como podemos ver me trae el ultimo registro y ya con el estado "PENDIENTE" reemplazado por "ENVIADO", pero lo que quisiera es que me traiga las mismas lineas y obviamente con la nueva palabra(ENVIADO).  ¿Qué podria Mejorar de mi codigo para cumplir con el objetivo? . Gracias por su tiempo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No tenes que mejorar nada.. si no entender tu codigo y leer la documentacion de las cosas que estas usando ;).

fijate que para abrir el archivo de destino, usas esto:

```
TextWriter SobreEscribirArchivo = new StreamWriter(@"C:\temp\MensajesxEnviarWsap2.txt", false);
```

Y si vamos a la [definicion del constructor de StreamWriter](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-io-streamwriter-ctor(system-string-system-boolean)) la misma dice, para su segundo parametro:

> append Boolean Es true para anexar datos al archivo; es false para
> sobrescribir el archivo. Si el archivo especificado no existe, este
> parámetro no tiene ningún efecto y el constructor crea un nuevo
> archivo.

O sea.. que en cada vuelta estas creando un archivo nuevo!!!!

Solucion rapida, cambia ese false por true...

Una solucion mejor, seria abrir el archivo una sola vez, guardar todo lo que corresponda y luego cerrarlo...

```
//aca si dejamos el false, porque queremos un archivo nuevo por ejecucion
TextWriter SobreEscribirArchivo = new StreamWriter(@"C:\temp\MensajesxEnviarWsap2.txt", false);
foreach (string fila in filas)  
{
    if (fila.Contains(estado))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(fila);
        string cadena = fila.Replace(estado, "ENVIADO");
        SobreEscribirArchivo.Write(cadena);
    }
}
SobreEscribirArchivo.Close();
```

Comment: Gandalf zaaapeee! Bien ahí hermano :D

Comment: Estaba todo en el cédigo pero como bien dices tenía que entenderlo totalmente, funciono bien con las aclaraciones que hiciste. gracias por tu tiempo . Exitos !